# Set Position With Animation

Tags: android, animation, button

I want to set the position of my Button with sliding Animation on Android. How can I do that?

Here's my Code

```
btnMain.setX(100);
btnMain.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {
            btnMain.setX(700);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will slide your button to horizontal direction. Change as per your need

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 0); //first 0 is start point, 100 is end point horizontal
    anim.setDuration(1000); // the argument is in miliseconds i.e 2000 = 2 seconds and so on
    yourButton.startAnimation(anim);
```

You can change the speed of animation by passing different time (in milisecconds) in `setDuration()` method.